# Why am I getting "access denied" using "dir"?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I have two machines, A and B, and a regular domain user called Bob that can RDP into both machines.

However, when I'm on machine A, that I open "cmd.exe", and then type "dir \machine-b\c$\", I'm getting "Access denied." Vice versa from B to A.

On both machine, I can just do "dir c:\" and see the output like normal.

I've search extensively on Google for answers to this problem but none of the solutions I discovered worked. There seems to be some permission settings that are missing.

What's the problem and how I can solve it?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a regular user and not an admin. RDP allows login to the computer. It doesn't give them admin rights. C$ is an admin share so a regular user wouldn't have access to it. Give them admin rights on both computers and it should work.